# Copying multiple files from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

We are modelling a directory structure in Azure Blob storage. I would like to be able to copy all files from a folder to a local directory. Is there any way to copy multiple files from blob storage at once that match a pattern or do I have to get these files individually?

Answer (score 2):

As you may already know, blob storage only support 1 level hierarchy: You have blob containers (folder) and each container contains blobs (files). There's no concept of folder hierarchy there. The way you create an illusion of folder hierarchy is via something called `blob prefix`. For example, look at the screenshot below:

[image]

In the picture above, you see two folders under `images` blob container: `16x16` and `24x24`. In cloud, the blob names include these folder names. So the name of `AddCertificate.png` file in folder 24x24 in blob storage is `24x24/AddCertificate.png`.

Now coming to your question, you would still need to download individual files but what storage client library allows you to do is fetch a list of blobs by blob prefix. So if you want to download all files in folder `24x24` (or in other words you want to download all blobs with prefix `24x24`), you would first list the blobs with prefix `24x24` and then download each blob individually. On the local computer, you could create a folder by the name of the prefix.

Comment: From where did you get this blob container in windows explorer? Is it only available for local blob storage?

Comment: Oh .. this is a screenshot of a tool called Azure Management Studio (http://www.cerebrata.com). Its a desktop based tool for managing Windows Azure. They also have a free tool called Azure Explorer for managing blobs.

Comment: Thanks, it looks good, I would wonder if anyone would give network drive kind of program for managing azure or any other cloud provider.

Comment: You're in luck :) ... check out Gladinet. Their tool allows you to mount a cloud storage account as network drive. Though I have not tried it so I would not know if the tool is kept up to date with the latest changes in Windows Azure Storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below code as a sample reference ((its written in javascript but you can easily map the logic to any language). This code is maintained by Microsoft.

https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools-xplat/blob/master/lib/commands/storage.blob._js#L144
https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools-xplat/blob/master/lib/commands/storage.blob._js#L689

The second link explains how to parse blob prefixes and get the  folder hierarchy out of it. 
It also shows how to download blob using multiple threads and ensure the integrity of the blob using MD5.

Just including the high level code that process blob path containing prefixes. Please refer above link for full implementation, I cannot copy paste entire implementation here.

```
if (!fileName) {
  var structure = StorageUtil.getStructureFromBlobName(specifiedBlobName);
  fileName = structure.fileName;
  fileName = utils.escapeFilePath(fileName);
  structure.dirName = StorageUtil.recursiveMkdir(dirName, structure.dirName);
  fileName = path.join(structure.dirName, fileName);
  dirName = '.'; //FileName already contain the dirname
}
```